# UICollectionView jumpy scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, scroll, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to create an interface that can hold "views" of different sizes etc. For this I am using a UICollectionView with these cells:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Card *card = [[[usermanager getSelectedUser] getCards] objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
    UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cardCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell addSubview:card];

    [cell.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor redColor].CGColor];
    [cell.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
    [cell.layer setMasksToBounds:NO];
    return cell;
}
```

Everthing seems to work fine until the amount of cards becomes too big and I have to scroll. The view jumps a little bit  when I lift my finger after scrolling. And I get some other weird UI issues. From what I have read this has to do with the reloading of the cells during scrolling. What would be the proper way to prevent that?

It is very important to note that the content is dynamic. The user should be able to add and remove cards at runtime.

Thanks

Comment: How long is `[[usermanager getSelectedUser] getCards]` taking to execute?

Comment: Do you have your own layout? If yes, make sure you subclass `UICollectionViewLayout` and use `UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext` when invalidating the layout.

Comment: @Dennis I am using the CHTCollectionViewWaterFallLayout

Comment: @trojanfoe about 66.0 ms

Comment: @BlackMagic how did you get on with this? I am working on an iPad version of my application and am only getting around 30-40 fps on an iPad air 1st gen. Nothing obvious showing up using cpu profiler (other than collection layout).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sort of figured it out. Some of my cards contained images, and everytime I would scroll the system would reload all these images from the memory. This made scrolling relatively slow and choppy.

Answer (score 2):

You stated in a comment that you are using `CHTCollectionViewWaterFallLayout`.
I used it myself in an application and from a performance perspective, it is not optimal (I checked the source code right now, and the crucial points still are the same). I had to do several tweaks to get it smooth.

First off, if you are targeting **iOS 8 and above**, there have been made huge improvements to `UICollectionView`, which you should absolutely make sure to use if possible. The 2014 WWDC video [What's New in Table and Collection Views](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/) gives you a good overview. The key point is that iOS 8 adds three new methods to `UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext`:

```
- invalidateItemsAtIndexPaths:
- invalidateSupplementaryElementsOfKind:atIndexPaths:
- invalidateDecorationElementsOfKind:atIndexPaths:
```

Using these methods together with `UICollectionViewLayout invalidationContextForBoundsChange:`  you can narrow down extremely the amount of items that your layout needs to handle. This will give you an optimal performance.

If, like me, you also need to target **iOS 7**, things get more complicated. There are two crucial methods in your layout that you can improve:

- First, `shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:` where you investigate the changed bounds and make sure that you invalidate the complete layout only if absolutely necessary.
- Second, `prepareLayout`, which should be called only if the complete layout should be invalidated.

In my case, I had to add floating headers, so I set a property `shouldInvalidateAll` in `shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:`, which I checked in `prepareLayout` to know if I really needed to prepare the layout from scratch.

It's actually not that easy (but possible) to get it smooth, but I hope that this sets a starting point for your version to improve.

Answer (score 0):

You could subclass the collection view cell and perform all layer initialization once when it's created and not everytime it is reused.

Also, when reusing a cell like this, you should check if the existing cell has already added a `Card`. When reusing, afaik iOS doesn't automatically remove added subviews (so for a reused cell addSubview could execute multiple times with different Cards, you can check this with view debugging ).

You also could lazy-load the cell content.

Comment: The problem is: All content is dynamic. The user can add or remove cards at runtime

Comment: @BlackMagic You just have to be sure to reuse those cells correctly. Maybe add a tag to the Card subview and each time before you add a new Card, just remove the old one (if exists). `[[cell viewWithTag:CARDTAG] removeFromSuperview]`

Comment: I am not sure you understand what I am trying to do. Every cell holds a single card. And the amount cells can vary, as well as the size of the cells individually

Comment: @BlackMagic I understand it, I was just saying you could eliminate some views which are loaded multiple times. And for the images, lazy loading is still an option.

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand from your code, on every cellForItemAtIndexPath  call you are making a new card object and adding it as a subview on the cell.

You are not actually using the power of reusing cell.
Try to add UI elements on the cell (storyboard or xib whatever you are using). Then set the values of those elements based on the index path. That would remove the lag in scrolling.

Also Import `<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

```
[cell.layer setShadowPath:[[UIBezierPath
                            bezierPathWithRect:self.bounds] CGPath]];

[cell.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor redColor].CGColor];    
[cell.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
[cell.layer setMasksToBounds:NO];
```

Comment: The problem is that I am using dynamic content. Users should be able to add and remove cards at will