# Only update the decoration view

Tags: ios, uikit, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm planning to add one view to my collection view at a certain position. Therefore I want to use a decoration view. Now the position should change every minute. How can this be done with `UICollectionView` on iOS 7 and iOS 8?

It seems that this can be done with [`invalidateLayoutWithContext`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewLayout_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionViewLayout/invalidateLayoutWithContext:), but can multiple [`UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext) be used for a layout?

When reading the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewLayout_class/)

> To define a custom invalidation context for your layout, subclass the
>   UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext class. In your subclass,
>   define custom properties that represent the parts of your layout data
>   that can be recomputed independently. When you need to invalidate your
>   layout at runtime, create an instance of your invalidation context
>   subclass, configure the custom properties based on what layout
>   information changed, and pass that object to your layout’s
>   invalidateLayoutWithContext: method. Your custom implementation of
>   that method can use the information in the invalidation context to
>   recompute only the portions of your layout that changed.
>
> If you define a custom invalidation context class for your layout
>   object, you should also override the invalidationContextClass method
>   and return your custom class. The collection view always creates an
>   instance of the class you specify when it needs an invalidation
>   context. Returning your custom subclass from this method ensures that
>   your layout object always has the invalidation context it expects.

it seems that only one invalidation context can be used, because you don't know when to return which context in [`invalidationContextClass`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewLayout_class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UICollectionViewLayout/invalidationContextClass).

There are times when I need to invalidate the complete layout (e.g. orientation change), but I also need to change the decoration view only.

Is this possible?

Other questions like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26998761/uicollectionview-is-there-a-way-to-reload-only-the-supplementary-views) , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29165496/uicollectionview-jumpy-scrolling) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20100680/using-invalidation-contexts-for-uicollectionviewlayout) doesn't provide a complete solution for my case or only for iOS 8.